# how to read root-context.xml file

Tags: java, spring

In my application I have both `DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` and `root-context.xml`. I configured all the bean in `root-context.xml` and I want to read that xml. I have used `ApplicationContext` to read that file but I got `ClassNotFoundException`. my both xml's are there  inside WEB-INF folder. if I create the xml outside i.e. src folder it is working fine but according to my project I can't change the location of the files so please tell me how to read the xml's which is inside WEB-INF.

Below is my code to read the xml file.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");
```

and

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/spring/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml");
```

Comment: Why are you even loading it manually? You should't be doing this in the first place...

Comment: What error are you getting while reading these files using your code in question?

Comment: Can you make the path like this `//WEB-INF//spring//DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml`

Comment: @ShishirKumar, He is getting `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @Deinum :i am using this in a util class it is niether dao nor service so i am not able to get the object using autowire concept even thought i am using component in that util class.

Comment: @shishir kumar  i am geting classnotfoundexception

Comment: @anilkumar why // i did not get you

Comment: Actaully, some times the file is not loaded due to the file path ambiguity...

Comment: Are working in any IDE(Eclipse) or normal editors ??

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` check with the libraries and refresh the project once if you are working in Eclipse

Comment: i am using eclipse IDE here classnotfound mean not with jar because of not able to identify the xml file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your application or servlet context in WEB-INF/web.xml and don't need init it manually.
Like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>ctxLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/app-ctx.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ctxLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/servlet-ctx.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And also you need to use `ContextLoaderListener` class

Comment: yes i configured my web.xml file this but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, you should put these files in classpath i.e. In your src directory of the IDE so it gets copied to the default classes directory.